# xampp cannont use phpmyadmin ( mysql error )

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, archlinux

I just installed xampp on my manjaro ( an archlinux distribution ) but I cannot use phpmyadmin as mysql seems to not respond.
As I use `sudo xampp start` the output is as follows :

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

But when trying to restart it using `sudo xampp restart`, it displays :

```
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

When connecting to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ a welcome is displayed but I do get 4 errors displayed in this order :

```
\#2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

After researching, I did notice that I am missing the `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` file but I do not know how to create and configure it.

I also tryed to use `mysqld` as seen in a few tutorials but got these errors :

```
2017-04-14 12:41:29 140391574202432 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB) starting as process 4483 ...
2017-04-14 12:41:29 140391574202432 [ERROR] mysqld: File './mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2017-04-14 12:41:29 140391574202432 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need to check your local socket configuration. This is configured in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and should look like the following:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Open the phpMyAdmin config file (`config.inc.php`) and change the socket address. Maybe there's no local socket configuration on your phpMyAdmin, or maybe it is different. This file should contain a line like (of course, adapt the address to what you found on `my.cnf`):

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';`

Answer (score 1):

Reset MySQL Root Password.

The problem will disappear.
Good time.

Answer (score 0):

Fix MySQL Database is not running in mac.
Open my.cnf file in `Applications/XAMPP/etc/my.cnf`

Then change MySQL port number 3306 to 3308

```
     # The MySQL server
     [mysqld]
     user = mysql   
     port= 3308     
     socket= /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then Restart the server again